# Check if positive value exist in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe:

```
A B C D
1 0 0 2
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

I need to select all values which are greater then 0 and put them in a list.
if row doesnt contain any positive value 0 should be written to list.

So, the output for given dataframe should look like this:

```
 [1,2,1,0]
```

How this can be resolved?

Comment: What if first row was `[1,0,0,2]`? --> `[1,2,1,0]`?

Comment: yes, that is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple loop you could use (looping through df.values gives us rows as arrays):

```
output = []

for ar in df.values:
    nonzeros = ar[ar > 0]
    # If nonzeros is not empty proceed and extend the output
    if nonzeros.size:
      output.extend(nonzeros)
    # If not add 0 
    else:
      output.append(0)

print(output)
```

returns:

```
[1, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make extensive use of `pandas` + `numpy` here:

1. Mask all values which are greater than `0`

```
m = df.gt(0)

       A      B      C      D
0   True  False  False   True
1  False   True  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
```

2. Mask rows which dont contain any values above 0:

```
s1 = m.any(axis=1).astype(int).values
```

3. Get all the values greater than `0` in an array:

```
s2 = df.values[m]
```

4. Finally concat both arrays with each other:

```
np.concatenate([s2, s1[s1==0]]).tolist()
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case , first `stack` with your df, then we `apply` your condition , if the row contain the none 0 we select , if all 0 , then we keep it as zero

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : x.head(1) if all(x==0) else x[x!=0]).tolist()
[1, 2, 1, 0]
```

Or without `apply`

```
np.concatenate(df.mask(df==0).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list).reindex(df.index,fill_value=[0]).values)
array([1., 2., 1., 0.])
```

Shorten the process

```
np.concatenate(list(map(lambda x : [x[0]] if all(x==0) else x[x!=0],df.values)))
array([1, 2, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a custom function which will process each row of the DataFrame and return a list. Then to sum returned lists.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  2
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  0  0

In [4]: def get_positive_values(row):
   ...:     # If all elements in a row are zeros
   ...:     # then return a list with a single zero 
   ...:     if row.eq(0).all():
   ...:         return [0]
   ...:     # Else return a list with positive values only.
   ...:     return row[row.gt(0)].tolist()
   ...: 
   ...:     

In [5]: df.apply(get_positive_values, axis=1).sum()
Out[5]: [1, 2, 1, 0]
```